# Выход из условия

Tags: python, условия

Имеется код, выполняющий набор функций (в моем самоучительном варианте это система регистрации аккаунтов и администрирование их). Для выбора нужного действия я ввожу цифру и т.д. Мне нужно, чтобы после введения цифры и выполнения кода, выполнение кода не заканчиволось (по логике он и должен заканчиваться, т.к. больше условий нет), а возвращалось на пару пунктов назад.

---

```
#стартовая точка
input = ()
if startch == '1':
    #что-то происходит
    #возвращается на стартовую точку
```

---

Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

применить while

```
cont = True #продолжать ли цикл
while(cont):
  input()
  if startch == '1':
    чего-то сделать
  .............
  if startch == 'выйти': #ввели значение, которое завершает цикл
    cont = False #на след. шаге while проверит значение cont и завершит цикл
```

Comment: Вместо cont = False, можно просто написать break

Comment: в IDLE все работает идеально, но при запуске .py файла (в винде) после первого input идет возвращение в первую точку (там у меня print с инструкцией)...

Comment: http://ideone.com
там код выложите